# How to get the alternate open g with unicode-math and Libertinus Math?

Tags: math-mode, unicode-math, libertine, newtxmath, variant

I was using [`newtxmath`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/newtx) with the `libertine` option (so Linux Libertine) with `pdflatex` engine before, but switched to [`unicode-math`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math) in `xelatex`.

`newtxmath` provided me with a nice open italic *g*, which seem to be the preferred form for mathematics. I don't know how to get that with `unicode-math` and the [Libertinus math font](https://github.com/khaledhosny/libertinus) (best choice for Linux Libertine). I dug in [`newtxmath.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/newtx/tex/newtxmath.sty) but couldn't find any useful information of what the package does to get the open *g*. I searched through Linux Libertine glyph tables and couldn't find it either.

---

`pdflatex` MWE with the desired open *g*:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

\begin{document}
\(g\)
\end{document}
```

[image: open g]

---

`xelatex` / `unicode-math` MWE with regular *g*:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

\begin{document}
\(g\)
\end{document}
```

[image: ugly g]

---

Possible solutions I can think of:

- Analyse how `newxmath` creates the open g and use that
- import the open g as vector graphics and make it a math letter, if possible
- Use just the open g of Linux Libertine (if there is one) together with Libertinus.

Comment: There is no open g in Libertinus Math.

Comment: I'm not sure that “the open form is preferred in math”.

Comment: @egreg: I found my source: the german book “Detailtypografie” has a chapter on typesetting math, made by Johannes Küster. It is stated that the open g is preferred, but it might be limited to german math typesetting ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imho newtxmath use this font with the option libertine for the g

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
\DeclareFontFamily{OML}{nxlmi}{\skewchar \font =127}
          \DeclareFontShape{OML}{nxlmi}{m}{it}{
           <-6.3>  nxlmi035
           <6.3-8.6> nxlmi037
           <8.6->  nxlmi03
          }{}
 \DeclareSymbolFont{gletters}{OML}{nxlmi}{m}{it}
 \DeclareMathSymbol{g}{\mathalpha}{gletters}{`g}
\begin{document}
\(abc fg \) 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the open g from `newtxmath` by declaring the symbol.  However, the `fd` file includes severals `\if` statements which have to be declared beforehand; but the font shapes can be defined directly.  (Probably doesn't work with bold math)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{ntxmia}{\skewchar\font=127 }
\DeclareFontShape{U}{ntxmia}{m}{it}{<->nxlmia}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{ntxmia}{b}{it}{<->nxlbmia}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{lettersA}{U}{ntxmia}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{lettersA}{bold}{U}{ntxmia}{b}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{g}{\mathord}{lettersA}{49}

\begin{document}

$\mitg$ $g$

$\mathbfit{g}$ \boldmath$g$\unboldmath

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've taken the liberty of modifying the code in order to avoid loading the (complicated) fd file. Feel free to revert.